# Braintree payment intigration in nodejs

Tags: node.js, braintree

I have to need to use Braintree for payment gateway in my web application for giving a gift to users.
I had made following code, by which I can make a transaction, but by the following code, I don't know how to use creaditCard/debitCard details and how to verify OTP number for the transaction.

> Routing file

```
var Braintree = require('braintree');

router
    .route("/api/gift/payment")
    .post(
        function(req, res) {

            var gateway = Braintree.connect({
                environment: Braintree.Environment.Sandbox,
                merchantId: 'my merchantId',
                publicKey: 'my publicKey ',
                privateKey: 'my privateKey'
            });

            gateway.transaction.sale({
                amount: '1.00',
                paymentMethodNonce: 'nonce-from-the-client',
                options: {
                    submitForSettlement: true
                }
            }, function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                }
                if (result.success) {
                    console.log('Transaction ID: ' + result.transaction.id);
                } else {
                    console.error(result.message);
                }
            });
        });
```

Can anybody give me proper guidelines for use this payment gateway secure in my web application?

Comment: Please check here. Official node js express example by braintree.
https://github.com/braintree/braintree_express_example

Comment: Your question appears too broad to be answered here. I recommend that you edit your question to be more specific. If you haven't already, I recommend you read through [Braintree's Developer Docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/overview). Also, the link @NikhilTalaviya provided is a great resource.